# Amending the Calendar form in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, column

I have a question about the Calendar app. I made the Location field compulsory from the Validation settings and a red warning message appears, when you try to save an event without its location. How can I make the Red asterisk appear next to the Location field, showing that it is compulsory? The SharePoint I can't be amended via InfoPath, otherwise I'd just change the form and add a new required field. I saw that people with similar issues simply hided the field, which they didn't want to appear via the css, and added a custom field. However, I wonder if there is a simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery for putting this dynamically.

Edit Following pages

1. EditForm.aspx
2. NewForm.aspx

Add a Script Editor Webpart and use below

```
<script>
    jQuery('h3').each(function(){
        if(jQuery(this).html().indexOf("Location") > 0)
            jQuery(this).html('<h3 class="ms-standardheader"><nobr>Location <span class="ms-accentText" title="This is a required field.">*</span></nobr></h3>');
    });
</script>
```